# How to change X and Y of a button

Tags: rotation, xamarin.ios

I'm using MonoTouch. When I rotate to LandscapeRight/Left I want to change the location of some of my buttons but I'm not having any success. I'm replacing the button.Bounds with a new rectangleF and setting that value in the WillRotate, but that's not working.

I am returning true in my ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation handler.

In principal what I'm trying to do is allow as much as possible to automatically rotate but then fix a couple of buttons that end up in a bad place.

Answer (score 1):

WillRotate is called before rotation, you're going to want to modify the bounds in DidRotate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to change Bounds and not Frame? Bounds will change the buttons' dimensions, where with the Frame property you can adjust X and Y. Other than that: Geoff said it already: you'll need DidRotate

René